# The table '#sql-5f8_9c' is full

Tags: mysql

im trying to delete a foreign key with the following syntax (5.0.45-community-nt):

```
alter table [table] drop foreign key [fk_name]
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
The table '#sql-5f8_9c' is full – 99543 ms
```

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE` often requires creating a copy of the *entire table*, so you need enough space on your filesystem to store two copies of the data concurrently as it does this table restructure.

It may seem odd that it needs to make a copy of the table since you're just dropping a constraint.  In more recent versions of MySQL, some `ALTER TABLE` operations have been optimized so they don't require a table restructure.  But you're using a version of MySQL from July 2007!

See also:

- [The table is full](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html)
- [InnoDB 'The Table is Full' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782150/)