# What is the default setting for innodb_data_file_path if it isn't specified in my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, innodb

What is the default setting for innodb_data_file_path if it isn't specified in my.cnf?

When I try to execute the following command on a 12GB table full of pictures

```
alter table `rails_production`.`pictures` change `data` `image_file_data` mediumblob NULL;
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table '#sql-7fe4_12c9' is full
```

I read another StackOverflow question [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full) that suggested I change my setting to the following

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:512M
```

When I looked in my.cnf I noticed I didn't have any settings for innodb_data_file_path, I'm wondering what the default value is?

Comment: can u use instead of it :  innodb_file_per_table

link :
http://www.pythian.com/news/1067/

Comment: That does seem like a good suggestion but it still doesn't answer my main question, what is the default value of innodb_data_file_path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just learned about

```
show variables;
```

Which will show you the value of those configuration options, in my case it was

```
| innodb_data_file_path           | ibdata1:10M:autoextend      |
```