# WordPress database error The table is full for query UPDATE

Tags: mysql, overhead, wordpress

In my wordpress multisite, in the main website, I got error when I tried to update any post or widget. When I put my site in debug mode, I found many error with: The table is full for query UPDATE or INSERT as:

- WordPress database error The table 'wp_1_options' is full for query UPDATE
- WordPress database error The table 'wp_1_comments' is full for query INSERT
- etc

And I think each table of my db seem limit contain only 3MB if I checked to the content of those error tables.

I use a database plugin for my wordpress site to check the db, I found most of them got "Overhead" size of 3MB.

What is the exactly issue with above info? How we could solve it?
What does Overhead mean? How can we solve that overhead issue?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full)

Comment: @maiorano84 Yes, ask my host to put:
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:512M

from above post solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue solved the same way as stated in the question: [ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full)

I asked my host to change:

innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:512M

It solved my problem already.

Answer (score 0):

So What your asking about is actually not possible in MySQL as I recently discovered. A cursor is declared at the top of a stored procedure with the rest of your declarations and MySQL's parse engine cannot manage conditional variable declaration, its all or none.

I came up with the following hack that let me get around this which is that I just declared every cursor I needed separately. I only had two, so this was not crazy:

```
DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT(user_id), applied_at FROM application WHERE job_id = JOB_ID_INPUT ORDER BY applied_at DESC;
DECLARE curs_all CURSOR FOR SELECT user_id, applied_at, job_id FROM application WHERE 1 ORDER BY applied_at DESC;
```

I would suggest that if you plan to have hundreds of conditionally created cursors then you may want to find another way to achieve your task in MySQL, or find a different tool if you cannot. Good luck.

Check this out for more detail:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html