# manage.py syncdb fails to create auth_user table

Tags: python, mysql, django, syncdb, nitrousio

Hello fellow stackoverflowers,

I am trying to follow the django intro [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/) using nitrous.io
When I run manage.py syncdb it creates a few tables till it hits the auth_user table.
Then it throws the following error:

```
Creating table auth_user 
DatabaseError: (1114, "The table 'auth_user' is full")
```

I don't know how to fix this error.
I am running mysql 5.6.13

Could someone please take the time to help!
Thanks a lot for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks similar to another question ([ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full))

I would suggest you to try the same fix by changing/adding the following line in your `my.cnf`:

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:512M
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I set the line, restarted the box and it works!