# How big the MySQL Data can be on a PC?

Tags: mysql, bigdata

I have a Mac Pro with i7 processor, 16GB RAM, and sufficient storage running Win 8.1 via Parallel on top of OS X Yosemite. I have a 23GB MySQL data and I am wondering if I am able to have such a big data loaded into MySQL in my PC. I started to import data but it stops after an hour throwing error

> Error 1114 (HY000) at line 223. The table X is full.

I googled the error and found the same error discussed in Stackoverflow (but not this much of data). I tried to resolve using the given solutions but failed. MySQL imports about 3G of data and then throws the error.

Now, here are my 3 main questions.

1. Is my data much more bigger than a MySQL data engine can have on a PC?
2. If this is not the case and I am good to go with that much data, do I have any configuration required to enable running a 23GB data on my PC?
3. Final concluding question is how big is big that one cannot run on its machine? Is it only matter to be able to store data locally or it needs some other things?

Comment: It can be as long as your piece of string.

Comment: This post may help identify the location of the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850287/error-1114-hy000-the-table-xxx-is-full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course MySQL on Windows can handle 23GB of data. That's not even close to its limit.

Keep in mind that a database takes lots of disk space for indexes and other things. 23GB of raw data probably will need 100GB of disk space to load, to index, and to get running. If you are loading it into an InnoDB table you will also need transaction rollback space for the load.

It seems likely that your Windows 8.1 virtual machine running on Parallels is running out of disk space. You can allocate more of your Mac's disk for use by Parallels. Read this.  http://kb.parallels.com/en/113972

Answer (score 1):

Your answers can be found within the [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html)

> The effective maximum table size for MySQL databases is usually
>   determined by operating system constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL
>   internal limits. The following table lists some examples of operating
>   system file-size limits. This is only a rough guide and is not
>   intended to be definitive. For the most up-to-date information, be
>   sure to check the documentation specific to your operating system.

[image]