# Error while restoring Mysql dump

Tags: mysql

Getting this error while restoring mysql dump.

> ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 1054: The table 'actual problem' is full

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full

Comment: Please provide more details on what you tried and where you are stuck trying to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

server memory can be full so the DB can not write the temp data. To solve it you just have to make some place on your drive.
 Try this as well:
edit config of db:

nano /etc/my.cnf

tmp_table_size=256M max_heap_table_size=256M

restart db