# Joomla Error 1114 K2 plugin

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, k2

I have Joomla 3 and I am Using K2 Component to insert articles on my site but I am having the follwoing problem with my k2 items.

Every time I save an Item I get the Follwoing error:

```
 Error 1114 The table 'ml9hn_finder_tokens' is full SQL=INSERT INTO `ml9hn_finder_tokens`  
(`term`,`stem`,`common`,`phrase`,`weight`,`context`,`language`) VALUES 
('indústria', 'indústria', 0, 0, 0.6, 2, '*'),('transformadora', 
'transformadora', 0, 0, 0.9333, 2, '*'),('os', 'os', 0, 0, 0.1333, 2, '*'),
('mentores', 'mentores', 0, 0, 0.5333, 2, '*'),('do', 'do', 0, 0, 0.1333, 2)
```

I only get this error here. When I create a new category it works fine.
Can any please help me with this issue. I am really not undertanding this issue.

Comment: Worth to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full

Comment: Hello Thank you for your comment but still the same. Still with same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was hosting problems. I talked to to company that is hosting my site and they increased the table memory and know it working all wright.