# Mysql "table is full" error

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am getting below error. I have found some similar problems but these suggestions doesn't solve my problem. ([ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full))

Funny thing is I am getting this error while inserting some data to "users" table and my application inserts below error to "logs" table.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1114 The table 'logs' is full
```

EDIT: My innodb file path defined as 'innodb_data_file_path', 'ibdata1:12M:autoextend'.

Comment: show the output from $df -h from your system. it looks like disk full

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full)