# MySQL InnoDB table full

Tags: mysql, innodb

in my Windows logs I can see C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: The table 'myTable' is full. Since I'm on Win32 with NTFS formatted partition file size of my myTable.idb (file size limit of "2TB (possibly larger)") may not be the root cause. I'm using innodb_file_per_table! 
OPTIMIZE TABLE does not work. What can I do? Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full#730600

Comment: doesn't solve my problem as MySQL is not configured with files_per_table = 1 in that case. That's why I outlined it.

Comment: Can you provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'myTable';` ?