# While adding new column , getting #1114 table is full mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add new column in existing table with 2.6dg data. but i'm getting

```
 #1114 table is full mysql
```

and i've edited `/etc/my.cnf` with

```
tmp_table_size=5G
max_heap_table_size=5G 
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:5G
```

but still i'm getting same error, please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Your disk is full?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full

Comment: @fancyPants at present table size is 2.6 gb, now iwant to create new column. Please help me