# MySQL : Error Code 1114. The table is full (table doesn't even exist)

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I dropped a table from my database and tried creating one with the same name. It gives me an error message saying exactly : "Error Code : 1114. The table 'COMMERCANT' is full" whilst it no longer exists on my database. What am I supposed to do, change or check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full)

Comment: Nope, I had already checked that post.

Comment: You post your question on the wrong site.  Try to post it https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Alright I'll try that. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the disk space is running out

```
df -h
```