# Restore Mysql dump to a mysql container fails with ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 7238: The table is full

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, containers, my.cnf

I am trying to restore a mysql dump of size around 18GB to other mysql server which is running inside a container using this command:

```
mysql -h example.com -u user -p matomo < dump.sql
```

But it fails with error:

```
ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 7238: The table 'piwik_log_link_visit_action' is full
```

Many other small tables are copied successfully but while coping this table it fails with above error. The size of this table is more than 2GB.

Based on different suggestions available on stackoverflow, I tried each one but nothing worked.

I tried adding 'autoextend' to my.cnf file:

```
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
```

I also tried to increase the tmp_table_size and heap_table_size by adding following param to my.cnf file:

```
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
```

Also, I made sure that the server (from where I am running the dump restore command) has enough space (more than 20GB of storage available). But nothing worked.

I tried debugging this more and found that, the docker container where mysql running has `overlay` filesystem of size 5GB which starts getting filled and as soon as it fills 100%, I get above error.

[image: docker_size]

I can't even go inside the overlay directory and keep deleting or freeing the space. Can anyone please help me here.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1114 (HY000): The table is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/1114-hy000-the-table-is-full)

Comment: @nbk no. As I mentioned, I tried all the options suggested, but nothing worked.

Comment: there is mentioned ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:512M and simply increase that number to 4 gb if need be or more

Comment: ok, let me try that again...

Comment: I added that `ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:10G` but still it didnt work. @nbk

Comment: you should ask at https://dba.stackexchange.com and post more of your my.cnf file