# Hyn tenancy showing Query Exception 'the table 'db' is full when creating new tenant

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, multi-tenant

I have been working on laravel angular project since last 6 months and now implementing hyn\multi-tenancy showing the error query exception:

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1114 The table 'db' is full (SQL: GRANT ALL ON `XYfeQKZivx`.* TO `XYfeQKZivx`@'127.0.0.1')
```

And I don't have such table in my database. Tried almost everything from the Internet still unable to find the solution for the problem.
Please any one help.
Thank You.

Comment: Which OS are you used?

Comment: using windows 10

Comment: Try creating new database.

Comment: Or this might help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/1114-hy000-the-table-is-full).

Comment: already checked that link but no help from there.

Answer (score 0):

answer simple
just go to phpmyadmin->mysqldatabase->sql section
and run query
REPAIR TABLE 'bd';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).