# XAMPP MySQL ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table 'db' is full

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to grant all privileges to a user for a new database I have created.

The command I run is as follows:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'dbname'.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

However, mySQL returns an error:

```
ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table 'db' is full
```

I am puzzled as I faced no such error previously when granting user access to other databases.

I have enough disk space and my setup for the innodb_data_file_path is as follows:

```
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
```

What am I missing here and how should I fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1114 (HY000): The table is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/1114-hy000-the-table-is-full)

Comment: Hi @MajidGhafoorzade, I have tried the methods listed there but issue persists